# Why so many layers on base images? Docker

Tags: unix, ubuntu, docker, virtualization

I've pulled `ubuntu:14.04` and after running `docker images -tree` I see the following:

```
└─511136ea3c5a Virtual Size: 0 B
  └─3b363fd9d7da Virtual Size: 188.1 MB
    └─607c5d1cca71 Virtual Size: 188.3 MB
      └─f62feddc05dc Virtual Size: 188.3 MB
        └─8eaa4ff06b53 Virtual Size: 188.3 MB Tags: ubuntu:14.04.1, ubuntu:latest, ubuntu:trusty, ubuntu:14.04
```

What is it? For example the first one. From my mind it seems like all layers is odd except the bottom one. Please, can anybody explain why they are need?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://www.askubuntu.com. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter. This isn't off topic - it's a Docker question, not an Ubuntu question.

Comment: suit yourself ;-) Not what I would call a programming question, but I'm glad you can answer it for the OP. Good luck to all.

Comment: unless there is a docker.stackexchange.com on the tracks, I think it's a pretty valid question for SO - anyway it's definitely not ubuntu-related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is there is a layer for each instruction in the Dockerfile used to build the image.

You can find the Dockerfile for your Ubuntu image [here](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/09e0fe385154ae9d23b231e2bfaa172258a9530b/trusty/Dockerfile).

From the `FROM` line we can see the image is based on "scratch", which represents the empty layer you can see at the top of your output. Each following line adds a new layer to the image. When you run `docker build`, you can see Docker building the layers and running the new instructions in the previous layer.

Comment: May be it is noob answer) but why in the dockerfile are less instructions than layers in the build image?

Comment: There are the same number - I was wrong about CMD lines not counting :)